# Update claims for all logged in users with Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

I'm using Owin for authentication/authorization and on Configuration change I'd like to update the claims for all users.

What I've done is created an event that I subscribe my Principal objects to and in the handler I update their claims.  However, in order to update claims I have to do something like the following:

```
    private void OnTimeOutChange(object sender, SystemConfigurationUpdatedEventArgs args)
    {
        int timeout = args.SystemConfiguration.ValueAs<int>();

        if (this.MyIdentity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == DemoIdentity.IPClaimType))
        {
            this.MyIdentity.RemoveClaim(this.FindFirst(c => c.Type == DemoIdentity.IPClaimType));
        }
        this.MyIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(DemoIdentity.IPClaimType, timeout.ToString()));

        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties{ IsPersistent = false  }, this.MyIdentity);
    }
```

The problem is that even though the handler in each Principal object gets hit, the only claims that get updated are for the user which is changing the configuration, i.e. the HttpContext.Current

I'm assuming this is due to using HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext() as this is the context of the current request.

Is there a way to get OwinContext globally or per every user, or is what I'm trying to do not possible?

Comment: You can add and maintain claims in the AspNetUserClaims table. As soon as a user logs on you can update the claims. The claims in AspNetUserClaims table are automatically added to the user.

Comment: Yes, during log in everything works well, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it while a user is logged in